# How can we handle MongoDB connections,schema?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I just start learning about Nosql database, and Mongodb. I have watched so many tutorials and still can't figure out the connections,schema and things in it

Lets say for example: 1. I have data's of customers who have similar set of data's 2. I have users with unique set of data

I don't know the term 'relationship' make sense for mongodb or not.

Can somebody please give something about  relationship,schema,what is joins..etc

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - this question is tough to address here.  You are better off just playing around with queries and tutorials on Youtube etc.

Answer (score 0):

- Collections are just like tables in MySQL.
- MongoDB stores data in the form of documents.
- Schema is the blueprint of a collection which decides the structure
  of any document to be stored in the collection.

For detailed info, you should read the docs in MongoDB site, install MongoDB in your local computer and play with it.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/databases-and-collections/